# How can I fix a matching error with dates in C# MOngoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation

I'm trying to match an Status object with Active flag (true or false) and the Status date.

I'm executing the code below, If I keep just the Active part it works, but when I add the Data part it returns empty. Data is an DateTime field in C#.

```cs
    var aggregate = orders.Aggregate().Match(new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"Status.Active", new BsonDocument("$eq", isActive)},
                    {"Status.Data", new BsonDocument
                        { 
                            {"$gte", begin },
                            {"$lte", end }
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Can you show the data and `begin` / `end` variables?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED, but with an workaround... I changed the 'DATA' attribute type to int instead DateTime and it worked.